# Getting an Error with Apachi POI in Java 10

Tags: java, apache-poi

I made a parser that reads excel spreadsheets with the apache poi with java 9 and my program runs fine when I export it to a jar file and run it on my computer. However when I try to run the program using java 10, I get a bunch of errors and it doesn't read the file at all.

[image: Error]

[image: Error Continued]

[image: Project Structure]

I'm running the latest version of apache poi and when I run the application in java 9 I get the warning messages, but the program still runs without any issues. These are my methods that I use to make the files and pass the file to the open method.

```
 @FXML
public void handleFileButtonClick() throws Exception {
    FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();
    fileChooser.setTitle("Please Select a SpreadSheet");
    FileChooser.ExtensionFilter extFilter = new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("Excel files (*.xlsx)", "*.xlsx");
    fileChooser.getExtensionFilters().add(extFilter);
    File file = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(mainGridPane.getScene().getWindow());
    if (file != null) {
        open(file);
    } else {
        Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.INFORMATION);
        alert.setTitle("File Not Found");
        alert.setContentText("File was not found or cannot be read.");
        alert.showAndWait();
    }

}

  private void open(File file) throws Exception {
    XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file);
    XSSFSheet spreadSheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
    Iterator<Row> rowIterator = spreadSheet.iterator();
    rowIterator.next();
    rowIterator.next();
    rowIterator.next();
    rowIterator.next();
    rowIterator.next();

    while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {
        row = (XSSFRow) rowIterator.next();
        Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();
        Job job = new Job();

        while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {
            Cell cell = cellIterator.next();
            DataFormatter dataFormatter = new DataFormatter();
            String cellStringValue = dataFormatter.formatCellValue(cell);
            switch (cell.getColumnIndex()) {
                case 0:
                case 1:
                    break;
                case 2:
                    if (!cellStringValue.equals("")) {
                        String[] date = cellStringValue.split("/");
                        LocalDate newDate = LocalDate.of(2000 + Integer.parseInt(date[2]), Integer.parseInt(date[0]), Integer.parseInt(date[1]));
                        job.setStartDate(newDate);

                    }
                    break;
                case 3:
                    if (!cellStringValue.equals("")) {
                        String[] date2 = cellStringValue.split("/");
                        LocalDate newDate2 = LocalDate.of(2000 + Integer.parseInt(date2[2]), Integer.parseInt(date2[0]), Integer.parseInt(date2[1]));
                        job.setEndDate(newDate2);
                    }
                    break;
                case 4:
                    if (!cellStringValue.equals("")) {
                        job.setTotalDaysPaid(Integer.parseInt(cellStringValue));
                    }
                    break;
                case 5:
                    break;
                case 6:
                    if (!cellStringValue.equals("")) {
                        String[] date3 = cellStringValue.split("/");
                        LocalDate newDate3 = LocalDate.of(2000 + Integer.parseInt(date3[2]), Integer.parseInt(date3[0]), Integer.parseInt(date3[1]));
                        job.setNextYearStart(newDate3);
                    }

                    break;
                case 7:
                    if (!cellStringValue.equals("")) {
                        String[] date4 = cellStringValue.split("/");
                        LocalDate newDate4 = LocalDate.of(2000 + Integer.parseInt(date4[2]), Integer.parseInt(date4[0]), Integer.parseInt(date4[1]));
                        job.setNextYearEnd(newDate4);
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
        if (job.getStartDate() != null) {
            jobs.add(job);
        }
    }
    workbook.close();
}
```

Comment: Try with a recent nightly build? IIRC there have been some Java 10 fixes recently

Answer (score 0):

I think you found a [bug](http://apache-poi.1045710.n5.nabble.com/Bug-62187-New-Compiling-with-Java-10-fails-with-ClassCastException-org-apache-poi-openxml4j-util-Zipm-td5730380.html), you'll have to do some digging on it's status.

Answer (score 0):

According to: https://poi.apache.org/faq.html 
“24. Can Apache POI be compiled/used with Java 10 or newer? 
Apache POI is not yet fully supported on Java 10 or newer. The binary formats (.xls, .doc, .ppt, ...) should mostly work, but unfortunately reading the newer XML-based formats (.xlsx, .docx, pptx, ...) is broken by a change to the ZIP file handling in Java 10, see bug 62187 for details and the latest state."